# install4j: Is it possible to make the next and finish buttons behave like default buttons, so they can be activated with Ctrl + Enter?

Tags: java, install4j

When testing a lot of installers, it would be very convenient to be able to speed through the wizards just using the keyboard.

E.g. by hitting <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts for navigating through screens are

<kbd>ALT-Right</kbd> for the "Next" or "Finish" buttons

and

<kbd>ALT-Left</kbd> for the "Previous" button